# How to get string length and subtring an User Defined Variables in Jmeter

Tags: testing, split, jmeter

I define an User Defined Variables with name:

```
message_title: "Test searching by title message"
```

Then I need to run a test case that input is a child string of above variables such as: "search" or "title".

I used an User Parameter and define 2 variables with name:

```
len : ${__strLen(${message_title})}

middle_search: ${__substring(${message_title}, 5, ${__intSum(${len},-5)})}
```

But when I run test case it throw error:

**51 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${__strLen(${message_title})}....**

How can I get length and a child string of User Defined Variables?

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, Any feedback on answer ? If it's ok , you should accept it and upvote so that it's useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For length this works for me, I store result in **len** variable:

> ${[__strLen](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strLensupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup)(${message_title},len)}

Then:

> ${[__substring](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#substringsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup)(${message_title},5,${[__intSum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)(${len},-5)},)}

Comment: It still fail again. Do you use any extra libs for jmeter? I download lastest version but it still error.

Answer (score 0):

As per [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation:

> UDVs are processed in the order they appear in the Plan, from top to bottom.

So you can basically go for 2 User Defined Variables instances

1. Add User Defined Variables #1 to your Test Plan and define the following variables there:

   - `message_title` = `Test searching by title message`
   - `len` - `${__strLen(message_title,)}`

     [image: JMeter User Defined Variables 1]
2. Add User Defined Variables #2 to your Test Plan and define the following variable there:

   - `middle_search`= `${__substring(${message_title},5,${__intSum(${len},-5)},)}`

     [image: JMeter User Defined Variables 2]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the defined variables in [Thread Group(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image: JMeter Useer Defined Variables Values]

Just in case check out [Using User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) article to learn more about User Defined Variables concept.

Comment: I tried to test as you guide but it still error. Do you use extra libraries for jmeter?